# Skip first row in python

Tags: python

I am using

```
for file in fileList:
    f.write(open(file).read())
```

I am combining files if a folder to one csv. However I dont need X amount of headers in the one file.

Is there a way to use this and have it write everything but the first row (header) coming from the files in the files?

Comment: `f.writelines(open(file).readlines()[1:])`? How large are these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use python [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html)

Or something like that:

```
for file_name in file_list:
    file_obj = open(file_name)
    file_obj.read()
    f.write(file_obj.read())
```

This solution doesn't load whole file into memory, so when you use `file_obj.readlines()`, whole file content is load into memory

Note, that it isn't good practice to name variables with builtin names

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in fileList:
    mylines = open(file).readlines()
    f.write("".join(mylines[1:]))
```

This should point you in the right direction. Please don't do your homework on stackoverflow.
If it's a cvs file, look into [python csv lib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).